# Laravel Passport TokenGuard::__construct() must implement interface

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-passport

I'm creating a rest api with Laravel and Laravel Passport. I try to access a route protected with the default laravel api auth middleware:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\ApiAuthController@login');
});
```

In the request header I pass `Authorization: Bearer <my_secret_token>` but I get this exception:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in /Users/markusheinemann/Projekte/Lycus/application/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 162
```

Here my request header:

```
{
  content-type: "application/json",
  x-requested-with: "XMLHttpRequest",
  authorization: "********",
  user-agent: "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
  accept: "*/*",
  cache-control: "no-cache",
  postman-token: "ebfa3211-958d-4042-ab6a-a488847fc2f7",
  host: "localhost",
  accept-encoding: "gzip, deflate",
  connection: "keep-alive"
}
```

Here my token creating process:

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('auth.failed')], 401);
    }

    $token = $request->user()->createToken('Lycus Frontend Client');
    $token->token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'accessToken' => $token->accessToken,
        'expiresAt' => $token->token->expires_at,
    ]);
}
```

Has anyone an idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your user model uses:

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{ 
    use HasApiTokens; 
}
```

---EDIT----

I have seen that login code in some guides on the internet, I personally think it is better to resend the request to the Passport API and let it login and create the tokens.

```
$request->validate([
    'email'    => 'required|string|email',
    'password' => 'required|string'
]);

$http = new Client();

try {
    $response = $http->post('/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'client_id'     => 2,
            'client_secret' => 'secret_key_from_passport_client',
            'username'      => $request->email,
            'password'      => $request->password,
        ]
    ]);

    return $response->getBody();
} catch (BadResponseException $e) {
    return response()->json([], 422);
}
```

---EDIT---
If you move User to other namespace don't forget to change in auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Auth\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Comment: Yes the model uses `HasApiTokens`

Comment: @Markus have you checked that the token is connected to a user in the passport Auth token table? Great name btw!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In my `oauth_access_tokens` I have entries which refferes to the given user. Also added the token creating process to this post.

Comment: @Markus can you share what route your are accessing, might be that you are accessing /user and not /api/user

Comment: Here a screenshot from my postman request: https://imgur.com/a/SKMaK0D 
Please note that I changed the default api context from `/api` to `/v1`.

Comment: That is strange, I don't see anything wrong. Is your user model standard, no changes? are you sure that you are being routed through the api routes?

Comment: I think the routing is not the problem. I've made three changes on the user model. 1. Moving to namesapce `App\Models\Auth`, 2. Adding the `HasApiToken` traits and adding a addational field (first_name).

Comment: @Markus updated answer your auth.php did you change it?

Comment: Yes I changed this configuration value after moving the model

Comment: Maybe I have a new entry point. I changed my login request to your recommondation by accessing `/oauth/token`. There I got a strange error message: `Unable to determine authentication model from configuration.`.

Comment: Hmm, does your namespace in your user model match the directory it is in? and second question did you change the auth.php api driver to passport?

Comment: Big, big facepalm. Instead of changeing the `auth.guards.api.driver` setting I've changed the `auth.guards.api.provider` option to passport. Now my problem is solved. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Great, was running out of ideas ;)